# Weighted polygon-feature-classes combination/overlay analysis using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, overlay, overlapping-features, analysis

I have several (sometimes, not always overlapping) Polygon Feature Classes which are all weighted/ranked through a field from 1 to 10 (10 is best). I would like to combine/overlay these layers them, but also use their rank information. Therefore not only the overlapping/intersected features should be shown in the result. A classification of the "best" places with the highest combined ranking should be shown in the result.

Is there a way to do that using vector tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this I would use the Union tool to calculate the overlap relationships between polygons.

I would then use arcpy.da.UpdateCursor to iterate through each polygon and add up the ranks/weights of any polygons that overlap in that area.

Comment: thank you. Why would you prefer the da.UpdateCursor over the FieldCalculator where you could also just sum it up using "rank1+rank2+rank3"?

Comment: It's just the first one that I thought of and wrote. Either should be fine.